# How to stop an Error from being caught by more than one except blocks?

Tags: python, exception

I have some code inside a try block that throws a ValueError. I have an except block that catches this ValueError and handles it. Once this is done I do not want other except blocks to catch this ValueError.

In the code below, there is another try except block later in the code and this ValueError is being caught by the second except too. How can I make sure the ValueError is caught only by the first except and not the second one?

```py
# Get features to plot
try: #First Try Block
    raw_features_list_1 = fsobject_1.genFeature(gmm.FftClassifier.fft_features)
except ValueError: #First Except Block
    pass

filtered_features_list_1 = np.array([row[0] for row in raw_features_list_1 if row is not None]).reshape(-1, 1)

try: #Second Try Block
    raw_features_list_2 = fsobject_2.genFeature(gmm.FftClassifier.fft_features)
except ValueError: #Second Except Block
    pass
    print("I am here")

filtered_features_list_2 = np.array([row[0] for row in raw_features_list_2 if row is not None]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

The above code gives me the following result:

```
I am here
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ff0067cb5362> in <module>
     11     pass
     12     print("I am here")
---> 13 filtered_features_list_2 = np.array([row[0] for row in raw_features_list_2 if row is not None]).reshape(-1, 1)

NameError: name 'raw_features_list_2' is not defined
```

This is because due to the ValueError generated by the first Try Block the second try block is not being evaluated and the the second Except block is being evaluated directly.

I would like to evaluate the first Try Blocks, handle the ValueError in the First Except Block. Then evaluate the second Try Blocks and, if it generates a ValueError, handle that in the second Except Block.

Comment: "Once this is done I do not want other except blocks to catch this ValueError." This makes no sense since the ValueError is already caught and handled. If there is a second `try` block with another `ValueError` this has nothing to do with the first one. If you don't want to have a `ValueError` thrown in the second `try` block just inspect why it is being thrown and avoid that with `if` blocks

Comment: It isn't `this` value error, it is `another` value error. each try can generate its own exceptions, and the corresponding except catches them. exceptions from one try can't be caught by another except

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes as you pointed out it seems to be that the second `try` is generating another ValueError. So I changed the code inside the second `try` block to not have the value error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry looks like what I am asking is already the default behavior of python.
I had another issue where the function generating raw_features_list_2 was throwing a ValueError and aborting before returning raw_features_list_2. So I felt as if the second try block wasn't being evaluated at all. I fixed my problem by handling the exception inside the function that returns raw_features_list_2.

As can be seen below,  python catches an exception only once.

```
In [26]: try: 
    ...:     1/0 
    ...: except ZeroDivisionError: 
    ...:     print("Caught") 
    ...: try: 
    ...:     pass 
    ...: except ZeroDivisionError: 
    ...:     print("Caught Again")
Caught
```

So my question is..kind of irrelevant.